# Jetpack Navigation Component Back Stack

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm using Jetpack Navigation Component with BottomNavigationView in my app. The application is something looks like this image: 
[image]

The app has 4 destinations:

1. Home
2. Categories
3. Account
4. Search(I open it when the user clicks on the search icon in the toolbar, also it shows in all destinations)
   When the user clicks on Product1, I show him/her Product1 details in another destination and if then the user clicks on the search icon the search destination will open and if he/she clicks on the back button I want to show him Product1 Detail destination but by default, the app shows Home destination. How can I fix it?
   I have many issues with the Jetpack Navigation Component back stack because it does not behave as expected. Also, I've read many articles and questions but they did not help me.

Comment: @john Joe Have you tested the sample app? The sample app has s bug, sometimes the app crashes. Also, I don't want to use multiple navigation graphs. Is there any better solution?